# How to convert two visually similar images in same scale

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, computer-vision

I have two images and both image contains same object(pattern) but scale is different of object. Any idea how to convert both image object in same scale.

Comment: This is not nearly enough information. I mean, it's so bad I cannot even find a decent suggestion how to improve this question.

Answer (score 0):

To make two objects in different images have the same size:

Find out how large each object is.
Calculate the ratio of both sizes.

Use that factor to scale one of the images (make one smaller or the other one larger)

Anything else depends on information you did not provide.

Answer (score 0):

By `scale of the object` I think you mean the amount of pixels or area of pixels the object takes up on the image.

If this is the case.

If both images are identical i.e taken from the same spot and taking account that the same face of the object was captured.

One of your images is a Zoomed picture of the other image. I Feel.